# How to add my own args to setup.py to compile cython and cpp?

Tags: python, cython

We all know that to compile cython and cpp, we need to write a `setup.py` file and then run `python setup.py build_ext`. But now I want to add my own args to it, and I don't know how to do that. For example, I'd like to add an arg "--debug" to control whether to compile with a macro `("DEBUG", "1")`, and I write like this

```py
# setup.py
import argparse
...

if __name__ == "main__":
    extra_macros = []
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--debug", action="store_true", default=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.debug:
        extra_macros.append(("DEBUG", "1"))
    extensions = [
        Extension(
            ...,
            define_macros=extra_macros,
            ...,
        )
    ]
    setup(ext_modules=cythonize(extensions, language_level=3))
```

But when I tried to run `python setup.py build_ext --debug`, an error occurred

```
usage: setup.py [-h] [--debug]
setup.py: error: unrecognized arguments: build_ext
```

It seems that my own args breaks setup's args so `build_ext` is disabled. So is there any way to add my own args to `setup.py`? Thank you!